# Проблема с плавной анимацией "transform-origin"

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Столкнулась с проблемой анимации `transform-origin`. Разрабатываю анимацию отрывного талона. При нажатии на синий квадрат, он принимает `transform: rotate(25deg);`, но при этом не принимается плавная анимация при отделении от красной части.

Какие есть варианты для реализации плавного отрывания при клике? На данный момент при нажатии он дергается и падает вниз.

[jsfiddle.net/dmqej865/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/dmqej865/3/)

```js
$('.cardRight').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("cutted");
});
```

```css
/* ticket */

.cardWrap {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.cardLeft {
  width: 400px;
  border-right: 18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardRight {
  width: 25%;
  border-left: .18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.cardSingle {
  width: 100%;
  border-right: .18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.cardWrap .form-group {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidded;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cardRight h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardRight,
.cardRight * {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cardRight.cutted {
  -ms-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: 00% 100%;
}

.cutted .cardRight h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cardWrap.list {
  cursor: default;
}

.cardWrap.list .cardLeft .btn-group {
  padding: 16px 0 0;
}

.cardWrap.list .cardLeft {
  width: 65%;
}

.cardWrap.list .cardRight {
  width: 35%;
}

.cardWrap.list .card {
  min-height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eventstage-6" class="cardWrap cleared" data-tt-widget-trigger="toggleStage" data-tt-stageid="6">
  <div class="card cardLeft">
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span> ---- Book NOW! ----
  </div>
  <div class="card cardRight">
    CLICK!
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span>
    <div class="card-top">
      <h1>BOOKED!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cпасибо.

Comment: какая именно анимация должна быть? просто поворот вокруг левого нижнего угла?

Comment: @Grundy да, то есть при отрывании он просто открепляется от правого нижнего угла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы применяете `transform-origin` **после** того, как он читает трансформироваться.
Примените его изначально..

```js
$('.cardRight').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("cutted");
});
```

```css
/* ticket */

.cardWrap {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.cardLeft {
  width: 400px;
  border-right: 18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardRight {
  width: 25%;
  border-left: .18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.cardSingle {
  width: 100%;
  border-right: .18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.cardWrap .form-group {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidded;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cardRight h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardRight,
.cardRight * {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.cardRight.cutted {
  -ms-transform: rotate(25deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.cutted .cardRight h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cardWrap.list {
  cursor: default;
}

.cardWrap.list .cardLeft .btn-group {
  padding: 16px 0 0;
}

.cardWrap.list .cardLeft {
  width: 65%;
}

.cardWrap.list .cardRight {
  width: 35%;
}

.cardWrap.list .card {
  min-height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="eventstage-6" class="cardWrap cleared" data-tt-widget-trigger="toggleStage" data-tt-stageid="6">
  <div class="card cardLeft">
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span> ---- Book NOW! ----
  </div>
  <div class="card cardRight">
    CLICK!
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span>
    <div class="card-top">
      <h1>BOOKED!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да действительно все прекрасно работает, спасибо за то что указали на ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас `transition` применяется ко всем свойствам, в том числе и к `transform-origin`.

По умолчанию, значение свойства `transform-origin` - 50%.

То есть изменения `transform-origin` проходит одновременно с применением `rotate`.

Для решения нужно либо установить `transform-origin` изначально.
Либо указать в `transition` конкретные свойства.

```js
$('.cardRight,.cardRight2').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("cutted");
});
```

```css
/* ticket */

.cardWrap {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.cardLeft {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 75px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardRight,
.cardRight2 {
  width: 50px;
  border-left: .18em dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 75px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.cardRight2 {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.cardRight,
.cardRight * {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cardRight2,
.cardRight2 * {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cardRight.cutted {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.cardRight2.cutted {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.cutted .cardRight h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eventstage-6" class="cardWrap cleared" data-tt-widget-trigger="toggleStage" data-tt-stageid="6">
  <div class="card cardLeft">
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span> ---- Book NOW! ----
  </div>
  <div class="card cardRight">
    CLICK!
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span>
    <div class="card-top">
      <h1>BOOKED!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cardWrap cleared" data-tt-widget-trigger="toggleStage" data-tt-stageid="6">
  <div class="card cardLeft">
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span> ---- Book NOW! ----
  </div>
  <div class="card cardRight2">
    CLICK!
    <span class="ticket-parts"></span>
    <div class="card-top">
      <h1>BOOKED!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```